# Numpy.gcd using more than 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, greatest-common-divisor

I am wondering if it is possible to compute the greatest common divisor for more than 2 arrays using numpy.gcd().
Using the following arrays for x, y, z:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[4,6,28],[2,5,6]])
y = np.array([[2,1,7],[7,23,6]])
z = np.array([[3,0,4],[7,4,3]])
```

Here the gcd code taking the 3 arrays:

```
result = np.gcd(x,y,z)
```

Which leads to:

```
array([[2, 1, 7],
   [1, 1, 6]])
```

result[0,2]

```
7
```

Instead of 7 shouldn't this be 1? Given the numbers 28, 7, 4, the following returns 1.

```
numpy.gcd.reduce([28, 7, 4])
```

So my question is if I am making a mistake at some point, or is numpy.gcd *not* capable of taking as input 3 arrays and simply computing the gcd over the first two arrays it receives as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gcd.html

The function signature is this:

```py
def numpy.gcd(x1, x2, /, out=None, *, ...):
```

If you call `gcd` with three arguments, you are basically doing `z = gcd(x, y)`. Therefore you need to come up with your own function. It could be something like

```
def my_gcd(x, y, z):
    return np.gcd(np.gcd(x, y), z)
```

which would return

```
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was indeed wondering in the function signature x1 and x2 if this means that it is limitted to two arrays, great to have your confirmation.